# Bad camelCase kern

Tags: kerning

What is the correct/best way to display camelCase such that an incorrect kern is not automatically applied between the words in the string?

---

For example in the camelCase string:

```
largestOfTwo
```

The `fT' kern is so close, that it almost looks like a ligature, which is quite inappropriate:
[image: bad kern]

---

Whereas,

```
largestOf\hspace{0.1ex}Two
```

appears roughly as I would like (with a small, but visible space):
[image: better kern]

---

How can all errors of this nature be suppressed automatically (and without changing font)?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}    
    \begin{document}            
        ``largestOfTwo"                 % looks bad 

        ``largestOf\hspace{0.1ex}Two"   % looks better
    \end{document}
```